# Ask 301 redirect, how to make .htaccess only part of the main domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have the link `http://domainold.example/content/`
after the content line there are many more `http://domainold.example/content/6745/66883/link` and `http://domainold.example/content/1246/4456/content/link` and so on there are hundreds,

how do I get the redirect to use 1 folder line from the main link `http://domainold.example/content/` and take all the advanced links like `6745/66883/link` or `1246/4456/link` etc.

how do I use the line `http://domainold.example/content/` without having to redirect the main domain link and we just redirect the link below

> - `http://domainold.example/content/6745/66883/link`
> - `http://domainold.example/content/1246/4456/link`
> - ***there are hundreds of links***

so that we can immediately redirect the link to the new domain

> - `http://newdomain.example/content/6745/66883/link`

> ***there are hundreds of links***

What does the `.htaccess` text look like?

Comment: If I understand correctly then you simply want a single redirection rule that redirects all requests to paths starting with a leading `/content/` to the new domain while keeping the actual path unchanged. If so, then just implement a single rule that matches the leading part of the path. That's all. So something line `RewriteRule ^/?content/ https://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]` ... Check the documentation of the rewriting module for details: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: What is in your `.htaccess` currently?  Do you have any rewrite rules?  If not, you can use a simple `Redirect` directive from `mod_alias`.